# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null whilst pulling YouTube videos from XML feed

Tags: php

I'm in the process of building a website with an auto-updating YouTube embed (when a new video is uploaded to the channel, the embed automatically updates).

I've managed to get it working on the whole, pulling the feed, etc. using cURL and SimpleXmlElement.

When putting in the last bit of the code to break the URL into into a variable, it encounter the above error.

The function code I'm using is the following:

```php
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    // Initiate the curl session
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Removes the headers from the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // Return the output instead of displaying it directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //set timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
    // Execute the curl session
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($ch);
    // Return the output as a variable
    return $output;
}

$feed = curl_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=CHANNEL_NAME");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
$url = $xml->entry[$i]->link->attributes();
$videourl = explode("&",$url['href']);
$video = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","",$videourl[0]);
```

I'm also using the following code to display the embed on the page:

```
<iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It's probably an extremely simple thing I've failed to do, but after numerous hours working on the code I can't work out where I've gone wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working code for your. `attributes()` returns an array() you can access `href` the in like this below.

**PHP**

```php
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    // Initiate the curl session
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Removes the headers from the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // Return the output instead of displaying it directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //set timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
    // Execute the curl session
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($ch);
    // Return the output as a variable
    return $output;
}

$feed = curl_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=CHANNEL_NAME");

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
$url = $xml->entry[0]->link->attributes()['href'];
var_dump($url);
```

**HTML**

```html
<iframe class="video" src="'.$url.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code worked, but I had to modify the code you provided slightly to get it to work fully with the embed. Added `$video = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","",$url[0]);` to the function, and had to use `<iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` as the embed.